# Problem with model-view-controller API architecture of web app

Tags: javascript, node.js, vue.js, express

So i am making a full stack App Vue, Node, Express, MongoDB. In main folder i have 2 folders- clinet with Vue UI with Vue router and server with Node.js, express and MongoDb.

Following MVC i have:

**userRoutes.js**

```
const express = require('express');

const userController = require('./../controllers/userControler');

const router = express.Router();

router.route('/').get(userController.helloUser);

module.exports = router;
```

**app.js**

```
const express = require('express');

const userRouter = require('./routes/userRoutes');
const app = express();

app.use("client/src/router/index.js)"; -> i wrote this line, without it the all UI doesnt work and on every page i get "cannot get" and vue router link
app.use('/api/v1/users', userRouter);
module.exports = app;
```

**userController.js**

```
exports.helloUser = (req, res, next) => {
  res.status(200).json({
    message: 'Hello World!'
  });
  next();
};
```

and i have also server.js that just working fine. Both server.js and vite app run on port 5173.

I dont understand why:

1. get:http://localhost:5173//api/v1/users doesnt work in postman? i tried all the combinantion and none works in postman, so there cleary something wrong.
2. How to replace this line:
   app.use("client/src/router/index.js)" which point to vue-router, because if i delete this the whole UI doesnt work? or should it stay?
3. Can vue-router router be the same as API endpoint? How to connect data from API endpoint from database with Vue UI?

Thanks in advance

Comment: "Both server.js and vite app run on port 5173" - how? It's unclear how it's going to work in your case.